# How to use a texture with particle system to create lightnings effect?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a lightning texture tga file type :

[image: lightning texture]

and i dragged the lightning texture to a new particle system :

[image: particle system]

two problems :

how to make the 3d start size to be random ?
from youtube tutorial he did something that give him a random settings ine the 3d start size:

[image: 3d start size random from the youtube tutorial]

but my 3d start size is not random and i'm not sure how to apply the random settings :

[image: how to apply the random ?]

the second problem is how to display the lightning in the particle system without the black box square around and to show only the lightning ?

[image: how to remove the black box square around the lightning ?]

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, I can't say much more than try to play with the parameters in the same section "Shape" where you can change the "randomize" parameters.

For the second question: Do you see that "Alpha Is Transparency" check mark? Yes, that's it. Solves your problem ;)

Comment: I found both solutions. so i will answer it. sorry.

Answer (score -1):

For the first problem the random on the 3D Start Size.

on the right of it there is a small arrow click on it to expand and then you have some options, select Random Between Two Constants or play with it with the other options. then you can set the X and Y and Z random ranges.

I marked with red circle the arrow to click and expand to get to the options.

[image: 3D Size Start]

The second problem was the box(cube) in black around the lightning.
to remove it just go to the object with the particle system scroll down to the bottom to the shader, expand the shader options and in Rendering Mode change it to Transparent.

I marked with red circle again on the right what you have to change to make it transparent.

and we have nice lightnings and this is the basic i guess but it's working nice.

[image: transparent shader]